# Symfony Installation gives fatal error

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I'm new to the symfony2 and I was following http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html for installation using Composer now

It gives me a Fatal Error after some time:

> monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log messages to Rollbar)
>
> Writing lock file
>
> Generating autoload files
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined method `Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::defineDirectoryStructure()` in `/Users/app/SymfonyStandard/RootPackageInstallSubscriber.php` on line 28

Comment: How are you setting up Symfony? using GIT, Composer or archive?

Comment: I'm using composer to install

Comment: God knows who downvoted, have an up vote. Especially as I've got the same issue :(

Answer (score 3):

@hap absolutely right on Debian/Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

is solving this issue. I think on another platform php5-curl will help too.

Answer (score 2):

**RESOLVED:**

Got the same problem. Deleted the file `composer.phar`, installed again via `curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` - problem persists

/path/to/webroot/project/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/ScriptHandler.php file does not have the method `defineDirectoryStructure()` in it

`symfony/framework-standard-edition (v2.6.1)`

`PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 (cli) (built: Oct 29 2014 11:59:10)`

problem here
`sensio/distribution-bundle (v3.0.11)`

Thanks @hap, this helped
`sudo apt-get install php5-curl`

Answer (score 1):

Just had this problem on Debian. For me the problem was that sensio/distribution-bundle in its last version (v3.0.12, the one introducing the defineDirectoryStructure function) requires the cURL PHP extension, which was not installed, so it installed v3.0.11 (which don't contain the required method).

After installing php5-curl, Composer finaly installed the last version of sensio/distribution-bundle and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem too ... Works on a debian distrib, but doesn't work on my wamp on windows 7 !

So tried to update my wamp, to get PHP5.5, reconfigure composer to use this PHP, still didn't work ..

Then I tried to launch the Console in Administrator mode, and launch :

"composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition sfproject/"

And guess what .... That finally worked !! With administrator rights ... Just give it a try ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. I just added in composer.json string "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*", And its working for me.

Also, i deleted my composer.phar and composer.lock files.

The problem, if you have in your project symfony 2.3 it installing dependencies for v 2.7 .

Answer (score 0):

I got this error from a install into a new vagrant VM, it would appear that something done recently has broken this as I managed to install a 2.6.0 version last week whilst testing, now it doesn't work.

After a bit of trial and error, it appears that the 2.6x and 2.5x branches are both affected and will not install, but 2.3x and 2.4x do install without the error.

incase anyone doesn't know how to install a specific version, just add it onto the end of the composer command, i.e.

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition . 2.4.x
```

VM: Ubuntu 14.01 / PHP 5.5.9

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in an Ubuntu 14.04 VM set up with PuPHPet and Vagrant/VirtualBox.

I've noticed that when I had the same problem, the DistributionBundle was severely out of date. Trying to upgrade it manually from composer.json (changing the version to 3.0.12, which was the las one available at the time I had the problem) produced a more verbose error, stating I hadn't installed php5-curl.

After updating the PuPHPet config file to include the cURL module for PHP and reprovisioning my VM, Symfony installed just fine, having installed the last version of Sensio Distribution Bundle, which contained the `defineDirectoryStructure()` method.